# Get string between a 2 strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a query to get the answer between 2 questions in string column, so basically the sample data looks like:

```
1. Over the past two weeks, have you felt down, depressed or hopeless? NO 2.  Over the past two weeks, have you felt little interest or pleasure in doing things?
```

so I need to get only the "NO" answer, the format is always the same

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I  strongly suggest you fix your design. The question and answer should be seperate columns, and each question on a new row.

Comment: the problem is that the company in which I am currently working is doing in that way

Comment: FWIW - As it is, there's really no way of parsing this for an expanded question list unless it is _guaranteed_ that the answer is between a `?` and a number followed by a `.`, and that there is only a single `?` as a delimiter for questions.  Maybe it's ok for the existing list of questions, but I would think that parsing logic is highly unlikely to be very stable.  You should be able to go back to the company providing this data and tell them that it's not a usable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text has not formatted well. If you can add a simple character between question and answers there will be a simple solution:
See my sample:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(4000) = N'1. Over the past two weeks, have you felt down, depressed or hopeless? NO ;2.  Over the past two weeks, have you felt little interest or pleasure in doing things? YES';

SELECT SUBSTRING(ss.value, 0, CHARINDEX('?', ss.value) + 1) AS Question, SUBSTRING(ss.value, CHARINDEX('?', ss.value) + 1, LEN(ss.value)) Answer
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, ';') AS ss;
```